# Get length of time while status remains the same

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a history table which looks like this:

```
| ID | DateChanged | Status |
|----|-------------|--------|
| 1  | 01/01/2019  | Closed |
| 1  | 05/01/2019  | Open   |
| 1  | 10/01/2019  | Open   |
| 2  | 01/02/2019  | Open   |
| 2  | 05/02/2019  | Closed |
| 3  | 01/03/2019  | Open   |
| 3  | 01/05/2019  | Open   |
| 3  | 01/06/2019  | Open   |
```

The history table is only ever updated when a change occurs, so I can say that the row returned by `MAX(DateChanged)` is the current state.

Let's say that `ID` relates to a shop.

I want to be able to identify the length of time that a currently open shop has been open for.

So I would get an output like this:

```
| ID | DateOpen   |
|----|------------|
| 1  | 05/01/2019 |
| 2  | (null)     |
| 3  | 01/03/2019 |
```

`ID = 2` would return null because it is currently closed.

I have tried using `LAG` to get the previous record:

`lag(status) over (partition by id order by datechanged)`

But I can't work out how to recursively increase the step until it finds "closed" rather than "open" and return that date.

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are only two statuses, you can use conditional aggregation to get the duration.

```
select id,
       (max(datechanged) -
        coalesce(max(case when status = 'closed' then datechanged end),
                 min(datechanged) -- in case there are no closed records
                )
       )
from t
group by id;
```

To get the earliest open date, you can use window functions:

```
select id,
       min(case when status = 'Open' and
                     (datechanged > closed_datechanged or
                      closed_datechanged is null)
                then datechanged 
           end) as open_datetime
from (select t.*,
             max(case when status = 'Closed' then datechanged end) over (PARTITION BY id) as closed_datechanged 
        FROM t)
group by id;
```

The subquery gets the latest closed date time.  This is then used to get the first open date after that.

Comment: Thank you Gordon. I didn't think about doing a sub query to get the latest `Closed` (or rather, `<> 'Open'` date and then use that. I've been approaching this from the wrong angle for so long!

Answer (score 1):

you are right, you need to use window functions

```
select
    id,
    status as last_status,
    date as last_status_date
from
    (   select
            *,
            row_number() over(partition by id order by datechanged desc) as rn
        from
            (   select
                    *,
                    lag(status, 1, 'first_record') over(partition by id order by datechanged) as prev_status
                from
                    <table_name>)
        where
           status != prev_status)
where
    rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your data schema.

But I suggest you to create a transaction and do two queries.

You cannot always put everything in one query.

Answer (score 0):

Another option using CTE's, without using Windows Functions, might not perform as good as the other answers, but thought I'd contribute an alternative:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tempTEST') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tempTEST

CREATE TABLE #tempTEST ( 
         [ID]           VARCHAR (50)    NULL
        ,[DateChanged]  DATE            NULL
        ,[Status]       VARCHAR (50)    NULL
 ) 

INSERT INTO #tempTEST (
         [ID]
        ,[DateChanged]
        ,[Status]
)

VALUES  ('1','01/01/2019','Closed'),
        ('1','05/01/2019','Open'),
        ('1','10/01/2019','Open'),
        ('2','01/02/2019','Open'),
        ('2','05/02/2019','Closed'),
        ('3','01/03/2019','Open'),
        ('3','01/05/2019','Open'),
        ('3','01/06/2019','Open');

WITH Get_Lastest_Date AS (
    SELECT  ID
            ,MAX([DateChanged]) AS [Latest_Date]
    FROM #tempTEST
    GROUP BY ID
),

Combine_Latest_Status AS (
    SELECT   G.*
            ,T.[Status]
    FROM Get_Lastest_Date G
        LEFT JOIN #tempTEST T
               ON G.ID = T.ID
              AND G.[Latest_Date] = T.[DateChanged]
),

Get_Earliest_Open_Date AS (
    SELECT  ID
            ,MIN([DateChanged]) AS [Earliest_Date]
    FROM #tempTEST
    WHERE [Status] = 'Open'
    GROUP BY ID
),

Get_Earliest_Open_Status AS (
    SELECT   G.ID
            ,G.[Earliest_Date] 
            ,T.[Status]
    FROM Get_Earliest_Open_Date G
        LEFT JOIN #tempTEST T
               ON G.ID = T.ID
              AND G.[Earliest_Date] = T.[DateChanged]

),

Get_Earliest_Open AS (
    SELECT   E.ID
            ,CASE WHEN L.Status = 'Closed' THEN NULL ELSE E.[Earliest_Date] END AS [Open_Date]
    FROM Get_Earliest_Open_Status E
        LEFT JOIN Combine_Latest_Status L
               ON E.ID = L.ID
)

SELECT * 
FROM Get_Earliest_Open
```